# jqGrid - datas returned as JSON but not shown

Tags: php, jquery, json, jqgrid

I've been reading lots of posts here about the same kind of issues, but none helped me solve this issue i got with jqGrid. I don't get what i'm doing wrong..

Here's the data returned by my php file (it's reversed ordered intentionnally because i'm sorting it desc) :

```
{"rows":{"1":{"id":"2","cell":["2","Italie","8",""]},"0":{"id":"1","cell":["1","France","8",""]}},"page":"1","total":1,"records":2}
```

Here's the end of the php file where i set the data before echo json_encode it :

```
// Préparation du tableau de retour 
$tableauGroupes = array();

// Si nous avons obtenu des résultats
if (count($listeFiltree) > 0) {
    foreach ($listeFiltree as $index => $groupe) {
        // On récupère le tableau contenant toutes les traductions pour le nom du groupe
        $tableauTraduction = (int)$groupe->getNomGroupe();
        // On récupère le nombre de sousGroupes dans le tableau de sousGroupes
        $nombreEnfants = count($groupe->getTableauCentreSousGroupe());
        // Préparation des lignes à afficher
        $tableauGroupes['rows'][$index]['id'] = $groupe->getGroupe();
        $tableauGroupes['rows'][$index]['cell'] = array($groupe->getGroupe(), $tableauTraduction[$langue], (string)$nombreEnfants, "");
    }
}

// Ajout des informations générales
$tableauGroupes['page'] = $page;
$tableauGroupes['total'] = ceil(count($tableauGroupes)/$limit);
$tableauGroupes['records'] = count($tableauGroupes["rows"]);


echo json_encode($tableauGroupes);
```

Here's the initialization of the jqGrid table (which used to be working just fine) :

```
// Configuration du jqGrid des centres
$("#listeGroupes").jqGrid({
    url: 'struct/<?=$rubrique?>/<?=$sous_rubrique?>/controleurs/tableauGroupes.php?sid=<? echo $sid;?>&sigle=<? echo $sigle;?>&langue=<? echo $langue;?>&nd='+new Date().getTime(), // Url de récupération des données
    height: tailleListe, // Hauteur de la grille
    ajaxGridOptions: {async: false}, // Surcharge des options ajax, lors des chargements de données
    datatype: "json", // Type de données récupérées par la grille
    colNames:["<?=THEAD_GROUPE?>","<?=THEAD_NOM_GROUPE?>","<?=THEAD_NB_SOUSGROUPE?>","<?=THEAD_ACTIONS?>"],
    colModel:[ // Configuration des colonnes
        {name:'groupe', index:'groupe', width:40, sortable:true, search:true},
        {name:'nomGroupe', index:'nomGroupe', width:100, sortable:true, search:true},
        {name:'nbSousGroupes', index:'nombreEnfants', width:40, sortable:true, search:true},
        {name:'actions', index:'actions', width:65, sortable:false, editable: false, search:false}
    ],
    rowNum:20, // Nombre de lignes par page
    rowList: [10,20,30,50], // Nombre de lignes par page possibles
    altclass:'odd', // Classe css des lignes alternantes (1/2)
    altRows:true, // Alternance de lignes
    pager: '#pagerlisteGroupes', // Identifiant du pager
    sortname: 'groupe', // Colonne par laquelle on trie par défaut
    sortorder: "asc", // Ordre de tri par défaut
    viewrecords: true, // Affiche le nombre de résultats
    autowidth: true, // Largeur automatique
    imgpath: 'css/jqGrid/images', // Chemin d'accès aux images
    pgbuttons: true, // Affiche les boutons du pager
    pginput: true, // Affiche un champ de saisie dans le pager, pour rentrer un numéro de page
    multiselect: true, // Permet de sélectionner simultanément plusieurs lignes
    caption: "Liste des groupes", // Titre de la grille
    //loadonce: true,
    sortable: true,
    ignoreCase:true,
    loadComplete: function(){
    alert("ici");
        initGrilleGroupes();
    },
    onSelectRow: function(id, statut){
        selectionnerGroupe(id);
    }
})
// Ajout du pager
.navGrid('#pagerlisteGroupes',{add:false,edit:false,del:false, search: false, searchtitle: "<? echo utf8_encode(html_entity_decode(TITLE_BOUTON_SEARCH));?>", refresh: false, refreshtitle: "<? echo utf8_encode(html_entity_decode(TITLE_BOUTON_REFRESH));?>"}, {}, {}, {}, { closeAfterSearch: true, drag: true, closeOnEscape: true }, {})
// Ajout de la barre de filtrage
.filterToolbar({searchOnEnter: false})
// Ajout du bouton de création de centre
.navButtonAdd('#pagerlisteGroupes',{
    caption: "", // Texte du bouton
    title: "<?=TITLE_BOUTON_ADD_GROUPE;?>", // Titre tooltip du bouton
    buttonicon: "ui-icon-plus", // Nom de l'icône du bouton
    position: "first", // Position de l'icône dans le pager
    onClickButton: function(){
        clicAjouterGroupe();
    }
});
```

Any help/suggestions would be welcome ;)
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i think i got this. Thing is the explanation is still really welcome.
If I don't reverse order the datas, it is working.

```
{"rows":[{"id":"1","cell":["1","France","8",""]},{"id":"2","cell":["2","Italie","8",""]}],"page":"1","total":1,"records":2}
```

This is printed properly. So if i need to sort my items by `cell[0]`, which is the id of the objects i'm fetching in my database, does the `id[0]`have to be the same one or is it completely different ?

By the way, i'm sorting my php array of objects with uasort:

```
uasort($listeFiltree, "CentreGroupe::trier".ucfirst($sortOrder).ucfirst($sortId));
```

Ok, i had to use `usort()` so that keys of the array are reassigned. Looks like the id really matters for jqGrid.
Hope this will help someone in the future.
Problem solved.
Peace